# I want to restrict the page reloading in a case where i am using the extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I want to restrict the page reloading in a case where i am using the extension. I have tried passing the params as cancel true but it blocks the sub_frame.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) { 
        var pattern = /^((http|https):\/\/)/;
        
        if(pattern.test(details.url)) {
            const url = `${CHROME_EXTENSION_URL}?url=${details.url}`;
            console.log(url)
            chrome.tabs.update(details.tabId, {url: url});
            return { cancel: true };
            // console.log(url)
        }
    },
    {urls: ["*://www.google.com/*"], types: ["main_frame"]},
    ["blocking"]
);
```

I have added the below screenshot for the example, actually i want the below extension to restrict the reloading or redirect to the page if the url changes, i am adding the url in the params.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXhXH.jpg